# Global Attribute for Cognito that available for all users

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am working with Cognito User Pool, and I wonder if we can have a way to create a custom global attribute that available for all users ? I want to create this because we want to update the attribute later with only one time and place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create custom attributes for your Cognito User Pool.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html and look at the section "Custom Attributes"